# Error while accessing Kibana UI using RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, kibana

I have a Cluster which is accessed by the users(developers) with the help of these 3 UI's (K8s Dashboard,Kibana & Grafana)

FYI,Kibana & Grafana are addons to the Cluster.

I want every user, other than ADMIN, should have read only access to Kibana Logging UI i.e., to view the Logs. So, I want to create an RBAC role. The role shouldn't change the user permissions in other UI's. It should only reflect in Kibana UI.

The user "xyz" is binded to the below Cluster-roles & roles-

In order to view the  K8s Dashboard:-

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: user-role-dashboard
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources:
      - services
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources:
      - services/proxy
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create"]
```

In order to view the list of namespaces in the K8s Dashboard:-

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ns-view-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "*"
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

The user set to have admin privilege with in the namespace(K8s Dashboard):-

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
   namespace: ns
   name: ns-admin-role
rules:
 - apiGroups: ["*"]
   resources: ["*"]
   verbs: ["*"]
```

Can anyone help me,"how to create a role which gives the read only privileges to Kibana Dashboard", regarding this?

Below, is the error which I'm facing as the user "xyz" is not able to view the Kibana UI:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kibana-logging\" is forbidden: User \"xyz\" cannot proxy services in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "kibana-logging",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

### **Updated**

Pods deployed on my Cluster

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-logging-0                 1/1       Running   6          239d
elasticsearch-logging-1                 1/1       Running   2          239d
fluentd-es-v2.0.2-5jmss                 1/1       Running   7          232d
fluentd-es-v2.0.2-tcgb6                 1/1       Running   5          239d
heapster-588bcd669c-qz2f8               1/1       Running   3          239d
kibana-logging-5fd7fcf8c-72grf          1/1       Running   3          239d
kube-dns-9c5fccf5c-b98px                3/3       Running   9          239d
kubernetes-dashboard-7f9755578c-kb9n6   1/1       Running   3          239d
monitoring-grafana-794779fc5b-rr2lx     1/1       Running   3          239d
monitoring-influxdb-67c5b7dbd6-xrplj    1/1       Running   3          239d
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding. Is it absent because you did not do it or is it absent because you forgot to add it here? I will try to recreate this on my cluster and post a better solution, but for now it would be nice to know if you attempted to create binding at all.

Comment: Hey..!Thanks for the Response. I binded these roles & Clusterroles to the user "xyz". I did not add the code but I have mentioned it in the description saying, "The user 'xyz' is binded to the below Cluster-roles & roles(in the top)". Looking forward to your response...

Comment: Can you provide more information please. You mentioned addons so this is minikube? Did you run it with --extra-`config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC`? Also could you share results of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`? Did you use any tutorial for setting up the roles? I deployed efk and will try to recreate this issue when I get more details.

Comment: Hey..! I have used 5 dedicated VM's(3 Masters,2 Worker Nodes). Yes I ran with Authorization.Mode=RBAC.I will update the content with the pods I deployed in my cluster.Yes..I used many tutorials to setup this Cluster.And I'm running my cluster with K8s - v1.8

Comment: but is this minikube? Because it seems so, but you claim you have 3 masters - which is not possible in minikube.

Comment: No it's not Minikube.As I already said, I have dedicated VM's.